# Getting on & mouseenter to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have:

```
$('div').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    // ... things to do
});
```

However, this is not working. I tried 'hover' and 'mouseenter mouseleave' all together but they are not working either, unless I go with delegate or live.

Since now it's "on" that shall be used, how can I get on and hover (or mouseenter) work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said it works if you use `delegate` or `live`, are you sure that the `<div />` you are testing this on is on the page when your jQuery event is wired up? Are you doing that jQuery call in the document ready event? i.e. `$(function() { /* wire up event here */ });`

Answer (score 1):

That works, i tried your code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ffHJX/

make sure, there's no old jquery library (which doesn't support on) being loaded